# while creating proxy, it asks for parameterless constructor. how to pass all those DIs to for proxy creation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mocking, moq, xunit

I was following [Creating Mock with Moq around existing instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59660284/creating-mock-with-moq-around-existing-instance)
while creating proxy, it asks for parameter less constructor. how to pass all those DIs to, for proxy creation.
i have already created all those mock object of DIs and created the service instance.

[Creating Mock with Moq around existing instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59660284/creating-mock-with-moq-around-existing-instance)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.